# Variable not retaining value

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am attempting to set a variable to results obtained from a query, but the variable is not retaining the value.

```
var queryString = "SELECT price FROM menu_items WHERE id = " + 
    req.query.items + ";";
mysql.pool.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields){
    if (err){
        next(err);
        return;
    }
    itemPrice = rows[0].price;
    console.log("item price is2: " + itemPrice);
});

console.log("item price is: " + itemPrice);
```

I expect it to print `"item price is2: 10.99"` and then `"item price is 10.99"` but it prints item price is `undefined` and then `item price is2: 10.99`

Comment: The `console.log("item price is: " + itemPrice);` statement will run first. Here the itemPrice variable has no data so it shows undefined.

When The `console.log("item price is2: " + itemPrice);` runs it has the itemPrice value.

This is because the callback function called in  the `mysql.pool.query`  function will run asynchronously.

Comment: How can I make it so that it waits until the query is finished?

Comment: You can't just wait until the query is finished. If you want to run the last console.log to run only after the query has finished you can return a promise from after the query executes and run the last console.log only when the promise is fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

```
var queryString = "SELECT price FROM menu_items WHERE id = " + 
    req.query.items + ";";
mysql.pool.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields){
    if (err){
        next(err);
        return;
    }
    itemPrice = rows[0].price;
    console.log("item price is2: " + itemPrice);
    console.log("item price is: " + itemPrice);
});
```

Any network calls, run asynchronously, so once the db call is made, the next lines start executing.

Using Async Await

```
const {promisify} = require('util');
(async ()=> {
    var queryString = "SELECT price FROM menu_items WHERE id = " + 
        req.query.items + ";";
        const query = promisify( mysql.pool.query).bind(mysql.pool);
        const result = await query(queryString)
            if (!result) {
                next(result);
                return;
            }
            console.log(result)
            itemPrice = result[0].price;
            console.log("item price is2: " + itemPrice);
            console.log("item price is: " + itemPrice);
})()
```

Comment: Okay, I can understand that, but how can I make it so that the next lines don't start executing until the db call is finished?

Comment: Please find the async await way, in the answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
var queryString = "SELECT price FROM menu_items WHERE id = " + 
    req.query.items + ";";
mysql.pool.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields){
    if (err){
        next(err);
        return;
    }
    itemPrice = rows[0].price;
    console.log("item price is2: " + itemPrice);
    console.log("item price is: " + itemPrice);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can do it using following method

export const getPriceValue = async () => {

var queryString = "SELECT price FROM menu_items WHERE id = " + 
    req.query.items + ";";
mysql.pool.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields){
    if (err){       
        return 0;
    }
    if(row) {
      return(rows[0].price);
    }

});
}
let priceValue = await getPriceValue();
console.log('price::', priceValue);
```

Comment: The values being returned are still in the callback so the async function will always return `undefined`. This doesn't `await` for the async function either.